# simplexml_load_string throws "Unregistered error message"

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have no clue what this means or why it continues to give me this error.

Do I actually have to use try and catch for this?

Here is my error message:

> simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Unregistered
>   error message {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):
>   simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Unregistered
>   error message at
>   /home/kjdion45/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/LeadController.php:128)

Comment: Can you show us a little bit of the XML you're trying to load?

Comment: The message you're seeing is coming from some error handler (probably part of a framework / library you're using) which is capturing the XML errors and turn them into exceptions; unfortunately, it doesn't know how to handle this message, so gives you a rather garbled default.

Answer (score 2):

This error message is [from libxml](https://github.com/ImageMagick/libxml/blob/master/parser.c#L537), there's likely some problem with the XML.

When working with SimpleXML, you can suppress error messages by calling the [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) function. This stores errors internally, so they can be retrieved as an array with [`libxml_get_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php).

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
if (count($errors)) {
    echo "There were errors!\n";
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "Error $error->code on line $error->line\n";
    }
}
```